# Notable spacing in rendering SVG in edge(chakra), firefox vs chrome | skewed layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

So I have this tricky layout that's giving me headaches.
I've placed few triangles (using svg `polygon`) and they seem to work fine in Chrome, but bug out a bit in Edge & Firefox.I tried using border and box-shadow to hide it, but it doesn't seem to help.

[image: screenshot]

Is there any way to hide the white gaps? (on grey, orange and blue parts) (If you don't see them at first - try to resize the window a bit and it'll snap at some point)

@update2: setting borders for adjactent div looks like a workaround for now

I've also tried using a single css `clip-path` with a polygon that's shapped like a trapezoid, but it's not widely supported. The other thing i tried is to use css transform `skew()`, but I found it troublesome to position properly, as the following sections have to move accordingly to the side to match the degree of skew.

If you at least think there's a better solution to make this, please give me a hint and I'll try it out.

---

Here's the code for the version with `svg` triangles:

[image: Edit issue: spacing in SVG render in browsers]

And for the `clip-path` version:

[image: Edit css polygon multi width layout]

And the `skew` version:

[image: Edit skewed divs take 2]

@edit1
I've discovered that setting a gradient could help, but it leaks out on the corner...

```
background: linear-gradient(left,
rgb(253, 96, 64) 0%
rgba(255,255,255,0.8) 8px,
rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%)
```

@edit2
Changing the div neighbouring to the triangle to:

```
border-right: 1px solid rgb(253, 96, 64);
position: relative;
margin-right: -1px;
```

seems to be a good workaround. I've updated it in the sandbox.

Comment: what does the first part (probably solved with judicious use of shape-rendering: crisp-edges) have to do with the second part?

Comment: it's basically the same layout but implemented in a different way, and i'm not sure if I should use one over the other

Comment: adding crisp-edges seems to solve it 80%ish
it still occurs on certain resolutions

Comment: Another workaround that is commonly used is to set a 1px stroke on the polygons. Eg. `<polygon points="100,0 0,100 100,100" fill="blue" stroke="blue"/>`

Comment: Personally I would redo the layout.  Turn the clipped image into an SVG, and make the triangles just be the div background.  No issues with cracks then.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau do you mean using svg clipPath? (something likes this? https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-wood-px186?fontsize=14) I can't really scale the image inside svg shapes

Comment: Yes.  Put the image into an SVG and clip (or mask) it to shape you want.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I can't seem to get it to scale to the container and to preserve the aspect ratio at the same time. Is it possible to achieve this? (demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/green-monad-0t8qy?fontsize=14)

Comment: @Dawid Is this what you are after? https://codesandbox.io/s/unable-to-preserve-aspect-ratio-xizjk

Comment: You're a magician